# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController - get an address from the ABRecordRef

Tags: iphone

Once I get an ABRecordRef from the ABPeopleNavigationController, how can I get the contact's street address(s) (if there is one)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
NSString* street = ABRecordCopyValue (record, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
```

For more information on property types see ABPerson reference.